# How can I change my Source code into a real application which can be install in windows or other OS systems using java programming language?

Tags: java

I would like to know, if I have calculator source code in java and I want that source code to be changed into a real application which could be able to install in any OS(operating systems), so how can I install such source code or transfer it in the way, which it will be able to instal on OS?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **jnlp** files. You can find example how it works in [Swing Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). At this page, you can see **Launch button** - this is it. You have to google how to create this kind of file, but I am sure you can do it with e.g. some *Maven* plugin.

You can create **exe** file, but this is only for *Windows*. Or create runnable **jar** file, this is good for *Windows* and *Linux* but you have to run it using installed *java* from `JRE` (this is not exactly like just download file, install and run it using an icon).